# New instances not resetting its Timers and Childs

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop, instance, program-entry-point

*(I'm working in AS3 and Adobe AIR for iOS SDK).*

The program has two classes: the first one is `Program.as` which is what the FLA file is linked to. In `Program.as` there's a function to start the program and another to restart the program. The second class is my `Main.as` class which calls the `finishNow();` function from `Program.as` to restart the program.

It runs fine on its first run-through. The problem is that nearly as soon as it restarts, it seems to KEEP restarting itself on its own. It gives quite a few `ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.` errors too. I've also noticed that some functions such as TIMERS do not start from 0 again when the program restarts?? I'm really stumped because the logic seems to be okay, but the traces say otherwise.

Putting traces inside `Program.as` shows that the `finishNow();` function is being called repeatedly after the first run. The problem lies with the `programRestartTimer` not resetting on the new instance. By calling the `stop();` function on `programRestartTimer` temporarily fixes this. From the `Error #2025` that keeps showing, I suspect that display Childs which were not removed (or similar – such as other Timers also not resetting) in the first run are causing this problem. This would suggest that either the program is NOT creating an entirely new instance, or it is not possible with AS3??

Program.as:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Program extends MovieClip {

        var runMain:Main;

        public function Program() {
            startNow();
        }

        function startNow() {
            runMain = new Main(this);
            addChild(runMain);
        }

        function finishNow() {
            removeChild(runMain);
            runMain = new Main(this);
            addChild(runMain);
        }
    }
}
```

Main.as:

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public var program:Program;
        var programRestartTimer:Timer = new Timer(8 * 1000);

        public function Main(stageHolderTemp) {
            program = stageHolderTemp;
            trace(program);

            someFunctionsThatDrawGraphics();
            moreFunctions();
        }

        function callFinishFunction():void { // this is called at the end of the animation
            programRestartTimer.start();
            programRestartTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, restartProgram);
        }

        function restartProgram(e:TimerEvent):void {
            programRestartTimer.stop(); // this line is a temporary "fix" to stop the program from constantly restarting
            // it doesn't actually fix the full problem
            program.finishNow();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should first remove your event listener on your timer in `restartProgram()` and instantiate your timers like this: `var programRestartTimer:Timer = new Timer(8 * 1000, 1);` so that each timer will only dispatch one timer event. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

It sure is possible in AS3 to design a class so that it will be able to re-initialize itself. But this requires carefully devising the restart routine.

First, your `callProgramRestart()` function adds a listener to the Program instance, but it is never removed, this will cause your program to reset twice after the second call, which is most likely the cause of your remove child errors - you are removing them twice in a row. You can completely eliminate the need of that listener by utilizing `flash.utils.setTimeout()` ([the manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout%28%29)) and targetting it to call `restartProgram` function.

```
function callFinishFunction():void { // this is called at the end of the animation
    flash.utils.setTimeout(restartProgram,8000);
}
function restartProgram():void {...}
```

Second, you should do the "full" reinitialization somewhere. Your method of creating another instance of `Main` class should most likely work, but you should clear your listeners off former `Main` instance properly before calling this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. I think I will stick to using `TimerEvents` as `setTimeout();` seems to be deprecated in AS3, even though it still works. Not to say that I have a lot of `TimerEvents` throughout the program. In regards to the "full" reinitialisation, does this mean that I will have to remember to ALWAYS remove ALL the displayChilds, TimerEvent Listeners, TouchEvent Listeners, etc, at some point in the program after they are added? Can you explain why I have to clear off former listeners before a new `Main` instance is created?—shouldn't everything in a new `Main` be completely new?

Comment: Well, if you don't remove all the listeners, your old `Main` object or its children, depending on what objects listens to events, will still react on certain events, not to mention it will not be GC'd, thus eventually your application will crash. Removing child objects is not necessary in this case, as if your parent object will stop being referenced from anywhere, its child objects will too get GC'd. Listeners are counted as an additional reference to an object in terms of garbage collection. You may avoid this by using "weak" reference in your listener (parameter `useWeakReference` as true).

Comment: It's a bit confusing when you say, '...your old `Main` object or its children, depending on what objects listens to events, will still react on certain events...'. In program.as the `finishNow();` function removes the the old instance before adding the new one. Or is this not actually the case (is my old `Main` still there)? I was under the impression that the new instance was just accessing the old listeners and Timers because they weren't cleared off – thus the need to fully reinitialise. I don't think I can rely on GC as they would need to be cleared exactly on the restart.

Comment: While there are event listeners attached to your old `Main` instance, yes it's still "there" as in memory, and it can interfere with your new `Main` instance, for example, if it triggers a static method or any SharedObject data change. No, your new `Main` instance should create its own `Timer` objects unless provided by `Program`, and should use its own `TimerEvent.TIMER` listeners. And here's the culprit, the events are the same if dispatched by old `Main`'s timers, or by new `Main`'s timers.

Comment: Okay I think I understand now. So basically my understanding is: the best solution is to remember to manually remove any `Timer` or `Touch`/`Click` event listeners in `Main`? Whereas display childs can be left un-removed?